# Why this jsfiddle crash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I'm doing a function to validate emails adresses, an user can enter several emails, separated by semicolon.
I want to try my function with different cases, so I made a jsfiddle.
But when i Try to run the fiddle, it seems it crashes when calling my function IsValidEmailFormat.

this is the function I want to test.

```
function IsValidEmailFormat(input) {
var isValid = true;
if (input.length > 0) {

    var emailsToValidate = input.split(";");
    //this regex for the common mail format
    var regExp1 = new RegExp("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?");

    for (i = 0; i < emailsToValidate.length-1; i++) {
        if (!regExp1.test(emailsToValidate[i])) {
            isValid = false;
            return isValid;
        }
        //TODO: Add more validations rules if neccesary

    }
}
return isValid;
```

}

Any idea? Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mspasiuk/LLx32/)

Comment: It doesn't seem to crash. What's the exact error you get?

Comment: Doesn't crash for me, maybe you are using a bad browser?

Comment: Note: With the `RegExp` constructor, escape sequences may need to be duel-escaped for both the `String` literal and the `RegExp` -- e.g. `new RegExp("\\.")` to match a literal period.

Comment: Do you want to know which emails are bad or if any of them are bad, or what?

Comment: Bear in mind that the line who calls the function is commented. Line 15. Try uncomment first.
I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to user `var`. What I think was happening is when you don't use var the variable becomes global and it was messing up your for loops. The for loop in `runTests` doesn't ever finish because you keep resetting `i` back to `0` or `1` (The max size of any `testEmails` array)

You also needed to escape things in your regular expression. I changed it to a regular expression literal so it would be easier to spot.

[So my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/powerc9000/LLx32/10/) should be working.

```
function runTests() {
    var div = $("#testResults");
    var line;
    for (var i = 0; i < testEmails.length; i++) {
        console.log(testEmails[i]);
        line = "<p>" + testEmails[i] + "</p>";
        result= IsValidEmailFormat((testEmails[i]));
        console.log(result);
        div.append(line);
    }
}


function IsValidEmailFormat(input) {
    var isValid = true;
    if (input.length > 0) {

        var emailsToValidate = input.split(";");

        //this regex for the common mail format
        var regExp1 = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/

        for (var i = 0; i < emailsToValidate.length; i++) {
            console.log("testing", i);
            if (!regExp1.test(emailsToValidate[i])) {
                isValid = false;//
                return isValid;
            }
            //TODO: Add more validation example

        }
    }
    return isValid;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `for` loops, you need to define `i` to be a local variable otherwise you will have issues with scoping and your loops won't work as expected.

Change these

```
for (i = 0; i < testEmails.length-1; i++) {
for (i = 0; i < emailsToValidate.length-1; i++) {
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < testEmails.length-1; i++) {
for (var i = 0; i < emailsToValidate.length-1; i++) {
```